# meaning of ここは in the context

Tags: meaning, grammar

I have found several occurrences of ここは in several parts but they do not seem to have the meaning of "here" but I may be mistaken

> 言っとくけど、私のスキルは半端ないわよ？本来なら、誰にでもホイホイと教えるようなスキルじゃないんだからね？
> やたら勿体を受けるアクアだが、教えてもらう立場なので**ここは**じっと我慢だ。
>
> But just you know, my skills are serious stuff. I don’t go around
> teaching them to just anybody, got it ? There was Aqua, trying to make
> herself important again -but since I needed her to teach me, I would
> just have to tolerate it.

source: この素晴らしい世界に祝福を！

Comment: https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%93%E3%81%93

This should make it a lot clearer.

Comment: You mean: 話し手が、自分をへりくだっていう。この身。わたくし ?

Comment: To my brain, this can work with different meanings of ここ, but I'll leave it to someone more knowledgeable than me to explain which interpretation is the proper one in this context.

Comment: ここ seems to be referring to the speaker here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @LonelyDriver 's link also explains, ここ has meanings that are quite abstract, such as time and situation. This sentence refers to ここ in the latter meaning. The weblio entry says:

> ３ 話し手や周囲の人が現に置かれている状況や程度 
> 3. The degree or situation that the speaker or people around the speaker is in.

So, from this definition, a rough translation of your sentence might be:

> ここはじっと我慢だ。
> This is a situation where  I should just put up with her.